# Conditional rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I have two dataframes:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6), 
           week = c(20,23,10,15,20,40,10,12), 
           var1 = rep(1, 8))
df2<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,5),
            week = c(18,19,22,8,9,14,9),
            var1= rep(0,7))
```

I would like to combine them with the following conditions:

```
1. Keep all of df1
2. Only add the rows from df2 where the df2$week = df1$week-1
```

Output would look like this:

```
    ID week var1
1   1   19    0
2   1   20    1
3   1   22    0
4   1   23    1
5   2    9    0
6   2   10    1
7   3   14    0
8   3   15    1
9   5    9    0
10  5   10    1
11  6   12    1
```

This is a variation on a previous question asking how to keep a row on one condition and the row above it on another. I have since subset the data into two data frames, assuming it may be easier to conditionally rbind them. I tried:

```
df3<-rbind.data.frame(ifelse(df2$ID==df1$ID & df2$week==df2$week-1, df1, df2))
```

But I get an error message:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.
```

I feel like this is very close to getting the output that I want, but I am not very experienced with rbind. Thanks!

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397798/keeping-a-row-that-meets-one-criterion-and-the-row-above-it-if-it-meets-another

Comment: In the previous question, all of the data was in one data frame, and I wanted to extract all rows where var1=1 and the row above it only if the week= week-1.I thought it may be easier to split the data into two and then add only the rows from df2 that met the criteria instead of trying to extract rows based on multiple criteria.

Comment: instead of `==` try `%in%` and `&amp;&amp;` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex joins can readily be specified in a straight forward manner using SQL.  We assume that you intended that the IDs be the same in condition 2 as well.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select b.* from df1 a join df2 b on a.ID = b.ID and b.week = a.week-1 
       union 
       select * from df1 
       order by ID, week")
```

giving:

```
   ID week var1
1   1   19    0
2   1   20    1
3   1   22    0
4   1   23    1
5   2    9    0
6   2   10    1
7   3   14    0
8   3   15    1
9   3   20    1
10  4   40    1
11  5    9    0
12  5   10    1
13  6   12    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# List the weeks preceding those in df1
df1_wks <- unique(df1$week) - 1

# Combine df1 with the appropriate rows of df2
bind_rows(df1, 
          df2 %>% filter(week %in% df1_wks)) %>%
  arrange(ID, week)
```

Output:

```
   ID week var1
1   1   19    0
2   1   20    1
3   1   22    0
4   1   23    1
5   2    9    0
6   2   10    1
7   3   14    0
8   3   15    1
9   3   20    1
10  4   40    1
11  5    9    0
12  5   10    1
13  6   12    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2[df2$week %in% (df1$week - 1), ])
df
   ID week var1
1   1   20    1
2   1   23    1
3   2   10    1
4   3   15    1
5   3   20    1
6   4   40    1
7   5   10    1
8   6   12    1
21  1   19    0
31  1   22    0
51  2    9    0
61  3   14    0
71  5    9    0
```